# JSF: <f:ajax> in <h:selectOneMenu> fires only after first change in Chromium, works in Firefox

Tags: ajax, jsf, chromium

This is my form:

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="propertyType"
                   value="#{myBean.propertyType}">
    <f:ajax id="propertyTypeChanged"
            event="change"
            immediate="true"
            render="searchForm"/>
    <f:selectItems id="propertyTypeItems"
                   value="#{myBean.propertyTypeList}"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <!-- everything else removed for testing -->
</h:form>
```

And in my  bean, I have added some debug logging for the propertyType setter to see if and when the event fires.
The `render="searchForm"` is necessary, because in the real use case, some fields are hidden/shown depending on the value in "propertyType".

When I test it in Chromium (I assume Chrome is also affected, but can not test it), the setter gets called at the first change only. And the re-rendering of the search form causes the visible value of the selectOneMenu to the one that was fired.
When I reload the whole page, I can do another change that gets successfully fired.
I assume Chrome is also affected, but I have no Chrome, so I can not test it.

In Firefox, it works reliably for any number of changes.

Do I need to do something special for Chromium/Chrome ?

Comment: Do you have the browser cache cleaned? Try cleaning it or from the incognito mode, otherwise.

Comment: Yes, and I also restarted the browser.